# Windows XP keeps bluescreening during install

Tags: windows, installation, bsod

As is typical I got roped in to re-installing Windows XP (because I'm a developer and so good with computers etc) on my mother-in-laws in PC.

I thought it might be a memory problem but no errors are apparent using [Microsoft memory diagnostic](http://oca.microsoft.com/en/windiag.asp)

Any idea's what the problem might be? Windows was running before I formatted, albeit very badly.

Comment: What's the STOP error on the bluescreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Check your install media. You can just look at the back of it, like Chris said. (Even you can download a new one (a MSDN/original untouched ISO) and burn / install that. No difference. I can provide you some, but I've got only hungarian installers. :P))

2) Check your cables (this also caused me a headache once).

3) Some hardware is not compatible, manufacturers provide custom drivers in these cases. Just check out the manufacturer's site.)

Comment: New media did the trick, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Does the problem occur at the same step during the installation process each time?  If so you may want to update your post and mention the amount of time remaining or the percent complete when the error occurs.  If the error occurs at different points during the installation, then it sounds more like a hardware issue.  If this is the case I would re-seat the memory sticks, CPU and the bus connections.

Comment: Also try cleaning the install CD and reader lens.